# How to see native code bytes from .NETCF JIT compiler on

Tags: .net, jit

Can anyone suggest a way (supported or unsupported) of getting a look at native code bytes compiled by the NETCF JIT compiler.  I happen to be on WinCE6.0 on an ARM platform.

I'm guessing that this can be done with a native debugger, but I'm trying to figure out (essentially) how I would get my bearings to know what I'm looking at.  Perhaps one could set a breakpoint in a P/Invoke call, and then step back into JITted managed code - the trick being knowing when you return to a particular routine that you're interested in.

My purpose is to determine why (in my case), JITted math code performance is significantly worse than equivalent C++ (native) code.  And yes, I'm aware that .NETCF doesn't have native floating point support.

Comment: Yes.  I'm sure that the both the C# and C++ versions were both Release builds with optimizations.  Also, they were not run under the debugger.  The performance difference is about 10x in my simple test case, which basically amounts to doing a+b+c+d a bunch of times (for + - * and /).  I didn't see any way to control debug symbol output for the .NETCF C# project.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, are you sure you compiled your code in release mode, with optimizations turned on and debug symbol output turned off? There have been many times when I've forgotten to compile in release mode for performance-critical code, only to smack my head hours later for my inane oversight. ;)